# Smart Queries That Deal With NULL Values

Tags: mysql, sql, null

I currently inherited a table similar to the one in the image below. I don't have the resources to do what should be done in the allotted time, which is obviously to normalize the data into separate tables break it into a few smaller tables to eliminate redundancy, etc.

My current idea for a short-term solution is to create a query for each product type and store it in a new table based on ParentSKU. In the image below, a different query would be necessary for each of the 3 example ParentSKUs. This will work okay, but if new attributes are added to a SKU the query needs to be adjusted manually. What would be ideal in the short term (but probably not very likely) is to be able to come up with a query that would only include and display attributes where there weren't any NULL values. The desired results for each of the three ParentSKUs would be the same as they are in the examples below. If there were only 3 queries total, that would be easy enough, but there are dozens of combinations based on the products and categories of each product.

I'm certainly not the man for the job, but there are scores of people way smarter than I am that frequent this site every day that may be able to steer me in a better direction. I realize I'm probably asking for the impossible here, but as the saying goes, "There are no stupid questions, only ill-advised questions that deservedly and/or inadvertently draw the ire of StackOverflow users for various reasons." *Okay, I embellished a tad, but you get my point...*

I should probably add that this is currently a MySQL database.

Thanks in advance to anyone that attempts to help!

[image: Table Example and Current Query Results]

Comment: Playing the devil's advocate here, what would be the rule if, for a given `SKU`, a column had `NULL` in only some of the records?  Would that column still get dropped?  By the way, I don't think you can do this without dynamic SQL.  Maybe we can find an alternative which would be a little less painful.

Answer (score 0):

First create `SKUTypes` with the result of

```
SELECT  ParentSKU , count(Attr1) as Attr1,..
FROM tbl_attr
GROUP BY ParentSKU;
```

Then create script which will generate an SQL query for every row of `SKUTypes`  taking every  AttrN column which value > 0.